# If $A=[a,b], B=[c,d]$ are intervals and $A+B=\lbrace x+y\ | x\in A, \ y \in B \rbrace$ , show that $A+B=[a+c,b+d]$.

Tags: calculus

If $A=[a,b], B=[c,d]$ are intervals and $A+B=\lbrace x+y\  | x\in A, \ y \in B \rbrace$ , show that $A+B=[a+c,b+d]$. for any arbitrary $a,b,c,d \in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the subject? What work have you done on this so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a high-level solution: The inclusion "$\subset $" is trivial. For the other inclusion, note that $A,B $ and hence also $A\times B $ are connected. Now, the map
$$
\Phi : A\times B\to A+B, (a,b)\mapsto a+b
$$
is surjective and continuous, so that $A+B\subset \Bbb {R } $ is connected and hence an interval. It is easy to see that $a+c, b+d\in A+B $, whence $A+B \supset  [a+c, b+d] $.

Of course, more elementary proofs are also possible.